# Error in OpenCV: getting \377 while printing intensity values from a MAT

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, opencv, mat

I am trying to access the values in a opencv Mat; but when I print the values I get the following:

```
   \377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377
```

My code is as follows:

```
        cv::Mat oneComp(yb-yt, xb-xt, CV_8U);
        cv::Mat currentLabelImage(drawing.rows,drawing.cols, CV_8U);
        currentLabelImage = (drawing == n+1);
        currentLabelImage.convertTo(currentLabelImage, CV_32F);

        for (int i = 0; i<yb-yt; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j<xb-xt; j++){
                std:: cout << currentLabelImage.at<uchar>(i+yt, j+xt);
            }
        }
```

I am doing this on Objective-C Xcode.

Comment: What do you expect the output to be?

Comment: I got it! I had to change <uchar> to <float>